# Identifying drupal installation on windows

Tags: 7, blocks

I don't want a google custom search to be shown on my development system which is on windows but it should be visible when on production system which is on Linux.

How do I check it?

This isn't working out. I've placed this code in the block "Pages on which this PHP code returns TRUE (experts only) " but it does not work in my Windows installation:

```
<?php
if(  file_exists("C:"))
{
return false;
}
return true
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by implementing the [php_uname()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-uname.php) function:

```
$os_name = php_uname("s");
if($os_name == 'Linux') {
  return TRUE;
}
//can apply additional checks for other OS
else {
  return FALSE;
}
```